# Kubuntu and KDE 4.10 PPA

Tags: apt, kde, ppa

I have messed up my installation, while trying to update to KDE 4.10. I added the backports PPA (ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports) and apparently did the upgrade. However, it looks like it was just partial. I see some packages at 4.10, and some others at 4.9.4. If I go to any KDE app and click on Help - About KDE, it displays 4.9.4.

For example, kdelibs-bin is at 4.9.4. If I inspect the package in aptitude, I see that the PPA source is listed as 4:4.10.0-0ubuntu3~ubuntu12.10~ppa1 but it is not selected.

On the other hand, I see kde-base-artwork as 4.10 from the backports...

What's wrong? How can I update everything?

Edit: today I see lots of packages suggesting update to 4.9.5... and the 4.10 version available but not selected...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRRR... once upon a time, I edited the /etc/apt/preferences file ... Now I just renamed it and everything works as expected.